# I can't figure out what v_out and v_in mean in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

know some basic SQL enough to fix some issues or at least understand how it works, but I got confused with this. I figured out that they're some kind of commands since they're not tables. But I can't find anywhere here or first three pages of Google what exactly does v_in and v_out do.

The most confusing part is:

```
--some code above
inv_docs.datdoc AS day,
inv_docs.nrdoc AS doc_num,
v_out.article_id AS article_id,
v_out.qty_out AS sent,
--some code bellow
```

Where did v_out come from? To what is it related? Also bellow where I get to FROM part:

```
FROM inv_docs_out v_out
     JOIN inv_docs_in v_in ON v_out.lotid = v_in.idlot
```

Now I have v_out from nowhere, and it's not even connected to inv_docs via a dot (eg. inv_docs.v_in).

Comment: Those are _table aliases_. "nick names" Handy when long names, or same table used twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [table aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)), for example if you do

```
SELECT * FROM table_with_long_name t
```

You can use `t` as an alias. For example

```
SELECT t.date FROM table_with_long_name t WHERE t.name = 'A Name'
```

So in your case, what the following query does is letting you use `v_out` instead of `inv_docs_out` and `v_in` instead of `inv_docs_in`.

```
FROM inv_docs_out v_out
     JOIN inv_docs_in v_in ON v_out.lotid = v_in.idl
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks. Any recommendations where I can improve my SQL? Since this seems like a basic thing and I didn't know it.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ is a good starting point and it gives code snippets in a variety of SQL dialects